# Im a really stumped on this Methods and Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, methods

**so I'm not really sure what to do what I've already done**
    /*
     * a collection of methods to be completed
     * complete each TODO body-code for the given methods
     *  use recursion for the first method and last method
     */

```
public class Methods 
  /*
   * method to compute value of f(n) where:
   * f(1) = 1
   * f(n) = n + f(n-1) for n>1, n is even
   * f(n) = n * f(n-1) for n>1, n is odd
   */
  public static int f(int n) {
    //TODO

    return 0; //dummy line, replace this
  }

  /*
   * method to compute the sum of the proper divisors of a given positive integer, n
   * e.g., if n is 12, the sum of the proper divisors is:
   * 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16
   * note: proper divisors are all divisors of an integer other than itself
   */
  public static int sumOfDivisors(int n) {
    //TODO

    return 0; //dummy line, replace this
  }


  /*
   * method that returns a String indicating whether a given positive integer, n, is:
   * "abundant" - sum of proper divisors is greater than n
   * "deficient" - sum of proper divisors is less than n  
   * "perfect" - sum of proper divisors is equal to n
   */
  public static String numberType(int n) {
    //TODO

    return "foo"; //dummy line, replace this
  }

  /*
   * method that returns the sum of the digits of the positive integer, n
   * e.g., if n = 5403, the method will return:
   * 5+4+0+3 = 12
   * note: the right-most (1's) digit can be found using n%10
   * the remaining digits (all but the 1's digit) can be found using n/10
   */
  public static int sumOfDigits(int n) {
    //TODO

    return 0;  //dummy line, replace this
  }

  //a dummy main method, not used
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This program is not meant to be run on its own.");
    System.out.println("This is just a dummy main method.");
  }

} //end Methods
```

**so yea any help would be great.**

Comment: Generally SO is not a site where other devs just fill in blank lines in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> so I'm not really sure what to do what I've already done

You actually wrote only method declarations.
Your task is really well documented, you may try out to implement the utilities(like a `public int[] divisors(int n)` and so on) and eventually come back here and ask help about your concerns, posting either code or errors.

PS:This seems an academic assignment , have you checked some books, or notes?